# OpenCV - convert uint8 image to float32 normalized image

Tags: numpy, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to convert parts of a Keras DarkNet code to try to make the code run faster.
Here is the code I'm trying to optimize:

```
model_image_size = (416, 416)

import cv2
from PIL import Image

frame = cv2.imread("test.png", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

im = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
im = Image.fromarray(im).crop((1625, 785, 1920, 1080))  # crop ROI

resized_image = im.resize(tuple(reversed(model_image_size)), Image.BICUBIC)
image_data = np.array(resized_image, dtype='float32')

image_data /= 255.
image_data = np.expand_dims(image_data, 0)  # Add batch dimension.

return image_data
```

This is my attempt to achieve the same output without using the intermediate PIL coversion to reduce time:

```
model_image_size = (416, 416)

import cv2

frame = cv2.imread("test.png", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

frame = frame[785:1080,1625:1920]  # crop ROI
im = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

resized_image = cv2.resize(im, model_image_size, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

resized_image /= 255.
image_data = np.expand_dims(resized_image, 0)  # Add batch dimension.

return image_data
```

However, upon running the code, it will return:

```
resized_image /= 255.
TypeError: ufunc 'true_divide' output (typecode 'd') could not be coerced to provided output parameter (typecode 'B') according to the casting rule ''same_kind''
```

It seems like I need to change the `uint8` type to `float32` before normalizing but I'm not sure how to achieve it with OpenCV.

Comment: Use `resized_image.astype()` to convert to float and then proceed?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `resized_image.astype(np.float32)` to convert `resized_image` data from `unit8` to `float32` and then proceed with normalizing and other stuffs:

```
frame = cv2.imread("yourfile.png")

frame = frame[200:500,400:1000]  # crop ROI
im = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

model_image_size = (416, 416)
resized_image = cv2.resize(im, model_image_size, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
resized_image = resized_image.astype(np.float32)
resized_image /= 255.

image_data = np.expand_dims(resized_image, 0)  # Add batch dimension.
```

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is that you are dividing and assigning to the same variable with `/=`. Numpy expects that when you do that, the array is of the same type as before, but you are dividing with a floating point number which will change the value type.

To solve this issue you can do:

```
resized_image =  resized_image / 255.
```

and it should work. But you have to note that it will convert the matrix to `dtype=float64`. To convert it to `float32`you can do:

```
resized_image.astype(np.float32)
```

or

```
np.float32(resized_image)
```

The `np` should come from:

```
import numpy as np
```

Comment: OP wants `dtype='float32'`. Dividing an 8-bit unsigned integer by 255 and casting back to integer leads to mostly zeros. Doesn’t seem useful.

Comment: @CrisLuengo True, I will change it to make more sense